# how to drop NAs only if all elements are NAs in a groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fff = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c'], 'value': [1,2, np.nan, 1,2,3,4, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I would like to drop the NAs by `group` only if **all** `value`s are Nas inside the `group`. How could i do that ?

Expected output:

```
fff = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'], 'value': [1,2, np.nan, 1,2,3,4]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `value` for `nan` and use `groupby().any()`:

```
fff = fff[(~fff['value'].isna()).groupby(fff['group']).transform('any')]
```

Output:

```
  group  value
0     a    1.0
1     a    2.0
2     a    NaN
3     b    1.0
4     b    2.0
5     b    3.0
6     b    4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

create a boolean series with `isna()` and then group on `fff['group']`, and `transform` with `all` , then filter out(exclude) values which return `True`

```
c = fff['value'].isna()
fff[~c.groupby(fff['group']).transform('all')]
```

---

```
  group  value
0     a    1.0
1     a    2.0
2     a    NaN
3     b    1.0
4     b    2.0
5     b    3.0
6     b    4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
fff["cases"] = fff.groupby("group").cumcount()
fff["null"] = fff["value"].isnull()
fff["cases 2"] = fff.groupby(["group","null"]).cumcount()
fff[~((fff["value"].isnull()) & (fff["cases"] == fff["cases 2"]))][["group","value"]]
```

Output:

```
    group   value
0   a       1.0
1   a       2.0
2   a       NaN
3   b       1.0
4   b       2.0
5   b       3.0
6   b       4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the answers already provided : Keep only groups where all the values are True, and filter the `fff` dataframe with the `result` variable.

```
result = fff.groupby("group").value.all().index.tolist()

fff.query("group == @result")
```